# What is $I \otimes I$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Supposing that $I$ is the identity on some Hilbert space $H$, what does the transformation $I \otimes I$ correspond to on $H \otimes H$? Is it the identity on $H \otimes H$? It seems like it should be but I'm new to this so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: don't worry, it is the identity. was that a sanity-check or are you looking for an explanation?

Comment: Sanity check, thanks! Though an answer could do some good since I couldn't find "I \otimes I" through a google search, maybe a student in the future will find it.

Comment: I added some more general facts about tensoring operators that should be more than enough to explainin why the identity tensored with itself yields the identity operator. Let me know if something is causing confusion!

Comment: High level answer: The tensor product is a functor on the category of Hilbert spaces (with bounded linear maps as morphisms). Since functors preserve identities...

Comment: @QuantumSpace haha nice, proof by nomenclature! one can climb even higher: the category of Hilbert spaces is monoidal. And I'm pretty sure one can climb much higher than that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OP suggests in the comments:

Let's have a more general look at operators of the form $u\otimes v$. Recall that the Hilbert space tensor product of two Hilbert spaces $H,K$ is the Hilbert space completion of tha algebraic tensor product $H\odot K$ under the norm induced from the (unique) inner product on $H\odot K$ satisfying $\langle x\odot y, x'\odot y'\rangle=\langle x,x'\rangle_H\cdot\langle y,y'\rangle_K$ for all elementary tensors.

If $u\in B(H)$ and $v\in B(K)$ the operator $u\otimes v$ is defined as the unique operator that is defined on $H\otimes K$ that satisfies
$$u\otimes v(x\odot y)=u(x)\odot v(y)$$
for all elementary tensors. It is proven that this is well-defined and actually $\|u\otimes v\|=\|u\|\cdot\|v\|$. You can check out Murphy's book for more on that and for detailed proofs.

Now how does one show that $I\otimes I$ is the identity map on $H\otimes  H$? Well, since $H\odot H$ is dense in $H\otimes H$ it suffices to show that $I\otimes I$ is the identity on $H\odot H$. But $H\odot H$ is linearly spanned by the elementary tensors, so it is enough to show that $I\otimes I$ is the identity on elementary tensors. But this is obvious by definition:
$$I\otimes I(x\odot y)=I(x)\odot I(y)=x\odot y.$$

This is in general how one works with operators of the form $u\otimes v$. Not only that, but one should also keep in mind the following "operation" rules:

$$(u_1\otimes v_1)(u_2\otimes v_2)=(u_1u_2)\otimes (v_1v_2)$$
and
$$(u\otimes v)^*=u^*\otimes v^*$$
where $-^*$ denotes the adjoint.